# How to restore same database when switching branch?

Tags: mysql, git, version-control

I have a question regarding the version control and database. My problem is that I have a branch **'b1'** that is stable, now I have created another branch **'b2'** and worked for couple of days. Now after few days I am to switching to my previous **'b1'** branch.

But my problem is Mysql database still having same database as **'b2'** branch. But I want to have the same database when I left with branch **'b1'**, only those table and those data.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Was your database (or, more likely, your database dump) under version control? Did you make backups? If you answer no to either of those questions then you are very likely out of luck.

Comment: Yes, I have taken backups for that version. But all That I want is to when I'm switching branches, it  should automatically restore database like git repository. Don't know wheather I have to modify my git commands.

Comment: My problem was the `.env` is not under version control and shared between the branches, and I didn't realise straightaway that I had to change which db connection string environment variable was commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this automatically, you would need to put all database files under version control. Additionally, since the database server doesn't expect those files to change without its knowledge, you would need to restart the server when switching branches. Of course, if the database is being written to, you would also need to commit the changes (in git) after every modification.

If you need this kind of functionality, consider switching to a server-less database that is more suited for this kind of operation. For example, [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) has no separate server process and holds all database contents in a single file.

Comment: [This previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846659/how-can-i-put-a-database-under-git-version-control) will also help you out to really understand what the issue is with databases and version control.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using development snapshot data you could just have two different databases one with the data that works with b1 and the other that works with branch b2.

In your branched code modify the database reference so you're referencing the new database there.