# Visual Studio database project alternative for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-project

I have been using database project in Visual Studio 2010 to maintain/version control database schema and are quite happy with that since I can also use VBDBCMD to deploy the version controlled schema to any database instance quite easily.

Now I need to work with PostgreSQL and I am wondering if there is any tool similar to the "database project" thing in Visual Studio to help version control database schema as well as schema deployment.

Thanks.

Comment: sigh, not even a suggestion? just downvote? no love for new comer?

Comment: Perfectly reasonable question, as this isn't a "what's best" or "what should I pick", but "does anything exist". There's not much out there, really.

Comment: wonder why I didn't find this last time :P Liquibase seems like the solution I am looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846659/how-can-i-put-a-database-under-git-version-control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing I could suggest would be Eclipse with the Toad plugin.

In general, shopping list questions are disfavored on Stack Exchange sites because they tend to solicit opinions and tend to go out of date quickly.

The other option is to use a source code management solution like git or subversion, and then just use your standard text editors on the SQL files.  This is what we do in the LedgerSMB project.

Comment: I know that's a long shot after a couple days of fruitless googling. But thanks for sharing your experience and I afraid that's what best for now.