# Git database changes in schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, git, git-branch

So there are 2 relevant branches. **notifications** and **shipping_options**.

I checked `notifications` out of `master`, then made 2 significant database changes:

- Created `GeneralNotice` model
- Modified **existing** `Notice` model, by adding a boolean `dismissed`

Then `shipping_options` was also checked out of master at the same state as `notifications`, and no database changes were made, only minor code changes.

I ran `rake db:migrate` the first time switching from `notifications` to `shipping_options` and the same vice versa.

At the moment, when I am in `notifications`, and run `rails c` I get the following:

```
2.0.0-p451 :001 > Notice
 => Notice(id: integer, title: string, description: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, kind: string, general_notice_id: integer, shop_id: integer, dismissed: boolean) 

2.0.0-p451 :002 > GeneralNotice
 => GeneralNotice(id: integer, title: string, description: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) 
2.0.0-p451 :003 >
```

- Notice has `dismissed` (as expected)
- GeneralNotice exists (as expected)

Then i switch to `shipping_options` and I hope you have been following because here comes the confusing part...

```
2.0.0-p451 :001 > Notice
 => Notice(id: integer, title: string, description: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, kind: string, general_notice_id: integer, shop_id: integer, dismissed: boolean) 

2.0.0-p451 :002 > GeneralNotice
NameError: uninitialized constant GeneralNotice
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/marcoprins/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2.0.0-p451 :003 >
```

- `GeneralNotice` doesn't exist, so apparently git is being very nice and helpful by changing the database according to my branch
- `Notice` **still has a boolean `dismissed`** ... Whaaaat???? Is git being nice or not?? HELP!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you've run the migration in the first branch (notifications), the column was added to the database table, hence it'll show if you inspect. [inspect](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/inspect) method works with the database table directly, reflecting the columns (attributes).
2. GeneralNotice: if you check your database, it would contain the table (general_notices) but since the file general_notice.rb in which GeneralNotice is defined is not present in this branch, it throws uninitialized constant error.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846659/how-can-i-put-a-database-under-git-version-control) and [this](https://processwire.com/talk/topic/3229-version-control-for-mysql-via-git-hooks/) for some ideas to put your db under version control.

Comment: Where can I see the table, just to know for sure. `GeneralNotice.inspect` throws the same uninitialised constant error

Comment: Login to the DB console. If mysql: mysql -u<uname> -p<pword> <db_name> and do show tables;

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you switch branch, and branches might contain set of different migrations it is wise to run `rake db:reset` which reloads database schema from `schema.rb` file.

In order to be sure your `schema.rb` is up-to-date in all branches it is good idea to run `rake db:migrate:reset` whenever you merge branches with new migrations. This rake task runs all your migrations from the very beginning and writes resulting database scheme to a file.