# How to include database in website deployment?

Tags: database, deployment

I try to setup a deployment workflow, but I am completely new to it. I consider to use Git and Bamboo and in this whole thing I am stuck with the database.

Let's say I want to make changes on a CMS website and keep my files versioned on git (bitbucket), I understand how to setup Bamboo that it can SCP the files to my webserver, but I don't get it how I can get the database into this whole system? Are there any tools I am missing?

What I want:
I want to be able to checkout my website files from the gitserver, make changes and send them back to the gitserver and this (via Bamboo) should push the files to the live or testserver.

But even after searching for hours, I don't get a smooth way how to handle the database (getting it local, making changes and pushing it to the server via git) or any other smooth way.

I know there are tools to quickly dump the db for WordPress sites, but for other CMS there are no such tools.

Any advice how to do this right?

Comment: This is a great article about putting your database on version control: http://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/

Comment: Other responses that can help you to clarify: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846659/how-can-i-put-a-database-under-git-version-control and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/241109/is-backing-up-a-mysql-database-in-git-a-good-idea