# using AWS CodeCommit for website development

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codecommit

I have a client who wants to use multiple developers to work on a wordpress website that is currently hosted on an AWS EC2 instance. Is using CodeCommit the right tool to use in order to have proper version control on this project? I get that is works through GIT and you can push files etc. But is it possible to apply the current EC2 site to CodeCommit including the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeCommit is just a Git server hosted and managed for you by AWS. It's really no different than using GitHub, BitBucket, GitLab or any of the other managed Git services. To be honest I usually use one of those other ones instead of CodeCommit since they tend to offer more features, like bug tracking and project wiki hosting.

If you want to automate deployments you will have to integrate with some other services, possibly AWS CodeDeploy or one of the many third-party services. You might search for "automated deployment tools" to see what I'm talking about, there are tons of different services out there.

> But is it possible to apply the current EC2 site to CodeCommit
>   including the database?

You can easily commit all the files that make up your WordPress site to Git. To commit the database to Git you would have to export the database to a file first. It is a very common practice to keep your database schema definition in source control. It is a less common thing to keep the database data in source control. You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846659/how-can-i-put-a-database-under-git-version-control) to see a previous discussion about storing a database in source control.

There might be some WordPress specific solutions to using Git that I'm not aware of. A quick search turned up [this interesting plugin](https://versionpress.net/) that might be useful to you.