# How to use version control on magento or WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, magento, github, version-control

Is there a way to use github version control in projects build on magento, WordPress or something with database? I would like to have files and databases in previous states and I can see whats changed in the code and in database.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the files, you can easily manage those for Wordpress and Magento with git. Before you make a repository with all the files though I would highly recommend finding a template .gitignore for both platforms. [Here is a gitignore for Magento](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Magento.gitignore) and [here is one for WordPress](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/WordPress.gitignore).

As for the database, there isn't a nice way to store it in git. You should read through the answers on [How can I put a database under git (version control)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846659/how-can-i-put-a-database-under-git-version-control). Basically if you want to use git then you will need to store the SQL dumps of the database which will probably require some sort of cron job or manual action to be done.